# Windows Update Error 8024200d and 80070002

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, windows-update

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that has been unable to install the July update 4025341.  All my updates run through WSUS and all my other servers installed fine.  When installing through the update client I receive an error code of 8024200d.  I have also downloaded the offline installer and tried installing manually.  That also failed with the error code of 80070002.  Any suggestions for getting this update to install successfully?

Comment: This issue is continuing to occur with the August Security Monthly Quality Rollup.  KB4034664 Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/466729/install-of-update-for-kb2667402-fails-with-error-8024200d?rq=1)? It's for a different update but sounds similar to the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the link @AaronD but unfortunately it doesn't seem to help with my issue.